# Absolute positioning with an onclick event works in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with a button that is styled by an absolute-positioned image and is attached to an onclick event. The code here works in chrome but not in firefox (in chrome I can see the alert after clicking the button, but in firefox clicking has no effect):

```js
function buttonClick(id) {
  alert("button clicked: " + id)
}
```

```css
.gameButtons {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 6vh;
}

#environment {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute; 
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="environment">
  <div id="allGameButtons">
    
    <button id="s1b" onclick="buttonClick(this.id);"><img src="https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/indiatoday/images/story/201708/cats-xl_080817011942.jpg" id="s1" class="gameButtons" style="height: 8vh; left:51vw; top:65vh;" alt="s1_button"></button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

After reading about the issue it appears that in firefox, the position:absolute applied to .gameButtons is placing the image in front of the button, making it unclickable. I have tested solutions including adding z-indexes to .gameButtons and #s1b, changing .gameButtons position to relative (which misplaces the image), and adding the onclick event in javascript instead of in the html. Any ideas how I may find a solution that works for both browsers?

Thanks, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Positioning the image doesn't change the location of the `<button>` that contains it.

Comment: Why don't you put the positioning on the button instead of the image?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar that was helpful. I found a solution by simplifying the html code that I'll post below

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
I've found a solution that simplifies the html code so the positioning only has to be applied to one element, and it appears to work in both browsers. I also found that using only one css class, with further attributes for images in that class, made things work more smoothly:

```js
function buttonClick(id) {
  alert("button clicked: " + id)
}
```

```css
.allGameButtons {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.allGameButtons img {
    position:absolute;
    height:6vh;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="environment">
  <div class="allGameButtons">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/306882/1537209550.png" style="height: 8vh; left:51vw; top:65vh;" id="s1b" alt="s1_button" onclick="buttonClick(this.id);" />
  </div>
</div>
```